# mysql:error while loading shared libraries

Tags: server, mysql

I am trying to install mysql 5.5.56 and i follow this tutorial.

https://gist.github.com/ahmadhasankhan/48fc9fc9a19807daef1622751a56884b

now mysql is up and running, but when i am trying to run the command `mysql --version`

it is showing the following error `mysql: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

i have install in on `ubuntu 20`

can anyone please tell me where is the problem and how can i get out of this.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install single deb-package which contains [this file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libncurses.so.5&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any) by

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5
```

Comment: thank you for your replay.
after intall `libncurses5` now i have this following error.
`LoadError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
`

Comment: Install the `libmariadbd-dev` package by `sudo apt-get install libmariadbd-dev` .

Comment: thank you man.
now that error has gone.